# How to get filename from file, look up that value in SQL table column, then return value from other column using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, foreach, ssis, file-rename

Using SSIS (2008) and T-SQL: How can you get the filename from a file and look up that value in a SQL Table column and then return a value from another column?

I have a folder which has .jpg image files of products. All the filesnames are in the format eancode.jpg, for example 1234567891023.jpg. Each filename is unique: one eancode per  image file for every product.

The productID (primary key, varchar) and the eancode (varchar) are stored in the same SQL table (without the .jpg extensions of course).

What I would like to do is rename the file from eancode.jpg to productID.jpg.

This is the process I had in mind, for example:

Files in FolderA:

- ean1.jpg
- ean2.jpg
- ean3.jpg

Steps/Tasks:

1. get filename ean1 from ean1.jpg
2. look up ean1 in Table column EANcode
3. return corresponding productid: select productID from Table where EANcode = 'ean1'
4. store returned value from step 3 into package variable (?)
5. use stored value of step 4 to rename filename
6. do step 1 - 5 in a foreach loop for all images; If no match can be found it should do nothing with the files.

The main focus of my question is on step 2 - 4. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested solution would work perfectly.  Set the result set (middle of the general tab) of the execute sql task to single value and then map the zero based result value to your package variable from within the result set tab

Comment: Yes! It works, I was almost there, but had to tweak some settings in the result set and also get the ? correct in the sql. Thanks!